# Merge all csv files in directory column wise

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, join, paste

Say the directory contained 3 csv files:

The first csv:

```
Name, John
Age, 18
```

The second csv:

```
Name, Jim
Age, 21
```

The third csv:

```
Name, Amy
Age, 22
```

I would want the result to be:

```
Name, John, Jim, Amy
Age, 18, 21, 22
```

It's important to know the directory could have n many csvs
I have both bash and posix shell available

Edit:

This feels like it should work but still has an issue with regards to order:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]?a[FNR]FS$2:$1FS$2}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' *.csv > results.csv
```

Which makes no sense as FNR 1 should be first in the array but it is printed last?

Comment: No unfortunately that post uses join which works on two files rather than working over a directory, I could of course do it in a loop but I feel like theres probably a simple one liner with awk

Comment: Okay so I got pretty close: ```awk -F, -v OFS="," '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]FS$2:$2}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' *.csv > results.csv```

Comment: But it doesn't preserve the row order, for example Age is now at the top as its sorted in the associative array alphabetically

Comment: Well done for your effort. I wrote recently a very similar answer, the main modification is that we keep the first file as is, so it was easier for me to provide some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was very close. Here are some modifications to make it work as required:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{
        a[FNR] = (FNR==NR ? $0 : a[FNR] OFS $2)
    }
    END { 
        for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]
    }' *.csv
```

`for (x in a)` does not guarantee the array access order, so in order to keep the order, we run a numeric index into the `for` loop. We could also use `for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++)`, but it's good to know that passing an array as an argument to `length()` is not standard for all awks, you can see this into the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

See also: [Scanning an Array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array)

Also we use the conditional `FNR==NR` which is an idiom for "when parsing the first file", and want to save the whole line `$0`, for the next files we just append the second field.

Comment: Thats cleaner thank you, whats the logic behind using OFS over FS?

Comment: It's the same here, as both are the comma, so we could use `FS` also. In general, we could need to output a different separator than the input one, so, as a habit, it's good to write `OFS` there (usually I 've been writing `FS`:).

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like it's in transposed tabular format ("xtab"), but with the separator for the key-value pairs being a comma instead of a tab character and with excessive whitespace added.

To clean the data up and to do the conversion to CSV, we may use Miller (`mlr`):

```bash
$ mlr --ixtab --ips , --ocsv clean-whitespace fileA fileB fileC
Name,Age
John,18
Jim,21
Amy,22
```

The `--ips` sets the "pair separator", i.e. the separator used between keys and values.

This is then easiest transposed with GNU `datamash`, assuming the fields do not contain embedded commas or newlines:

```bash
$ mlr --ixtab --ips , --ocsv clean-whitespace fileA fileB fileC | datamash -t, transpose
Name,John,Jim,Amy
Age,18,21,22
```

If the input fields contain commas, we can specify another output field delimiter (one that does not occur in the data), and then instruct `datamash` to use that instead:

```bash
$ mlr --ixtab --ips , --ocsv --ofs pipe clean-whitespace fileA fileB fileC | datamash -t '|' transpose
Name|John, the dapper|Jim, the mighty|Amy, the awesome
Age|18|21|22
```

Comment: That is very nice! And educational...